# initializing const variables after the declaration C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare a constant variable in `C++`;

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <pthread.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        using namespace std;

        //
        // declare the mutex
        //
        static pthread_mutex_t mutex    = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

        //
        // AVOID NEGATIVE NUMBERS
        //
        unsigned int MAXSIZE = 0;
        unsigned int head = 0;
        unsigned int tail = 0;  

        //
        // return a empty circular queue
        //
        int* initialize(int size){

           MAXSIZE = size;
           pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
           int* queue = new int[ MAXSIZE ];
           // initialize each position to zero ( explicitly )
           for(int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++){
            queue[i] = 0;
           } 

           pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
           return queue;
        }

        //
        // enqueue number into the queue
        // returns the position it was stored
        //
        void* enqueue( void* local_queue, void* local_data ){
           // ASSERT ONLY ONE THREAD EACH  TIME
           pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
           // convert back to int
           int data = *((int*)(&local_data));
           int* queue = (int*)local_queue;

           queue[tail] = data;
           tail = (tail+1) % MAXSIZE;

           pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
           cout << "Tail: " << tail << endl;
        }

        //
        // dequeue, given the queue
        //
        void* dequeue( void* queue ){
           int temp;
           pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
           int* local_queue = ( int* )queue; 
           temp = local_queue[ head ];
           head = ( head + 1 ) % MAXSIZE;

           pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
           cout << "Removed: " << temp << endl;
    }

    // 
    // print the queue as it is
    //
    void* display( void* local_queue ){
       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
       int* queue = (int*)local_queue;
       if( head == tail ){
        cout << "Queue underflow" << endl;
       }
       else{
        //
        // prints each element in the queue
        //
        for( unsigned int i = head; i < tail; i = (i+1) % MAXSIZE ){
            cout << queue[i] << endl;
        }
       }
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
    }

    //
    // delete the memory allocated to the queue
    //
    void remove( int* queue){
       delete queue;
    }

    //
    // explain the user how to run the program
    //
    void usage(){
      cout << "Usage: " << endl; 
      cout << "    ./queue [size] [elements]" << endl;
      cout << "ex: ./queue 5 0 1 2 3 4 5" << endl;
    }

    //
    // main function, the tests are done in the for loop
    //
    int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){

       pthread_t threads[5];

       if(argc < 2){
        cout << "Args must be at least 1 " << endl;
        usage();
        return -1;
       }

       for(size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++){   
        unsigned int size = atoi( argv[1] );
        cout << "Size: " << size << endl;
        int* queue = initialize(size);

        for(size_t i = 2; i < argc; i++){
            enqueue( queue, (void*)atoi( argv[i] ) );
        }
            pthread_create( &threads[j], NULL, dequeue, (void*)queue );
        // make sure memory is freed 
        // finally end the thread
        pthread_join( threads[j], NULL );
        remove(queue);
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

I would like to have `unsigned int MAXSIZE = 0;` declared as `const unsigned int MAXSIZE;` So I could initialize that at `runtime`. I know it can be done in the constructor of `class`, however I would like to know whether there is a way to initialize `MAXSIZE` to `size` which  is given by the user. `MAXSIZE` is used to implement the circular queue implemented in an array was shown, so it's important to `MAXSIZE` to be declared as `const` to avoid being changed and then affect the `circular` operation of the queue.
Thanks.
**I hope I clarify my question enough to have a more precise answer. I've added all my code into the question for completeness and for the sake of the community. **

Comment: Why not initialize `MAXSIZE` in the constructor? What happens if someone calls `initialize` twice?

Comment: @TravisGockel It's just a function, not a constructor.

Comment: So `MAXSIZE`, `queue` and `mutex` are just three global variables? It seems like something better encapsulated as a `class`. Your `initialize` function is certainly acquiring a resource and I'm guessing you have some way to destroy said resource. It's your call, but seems like a really obvious use case for a `class`.

Comment: No need for the mutex in `initialize`, you haven't exposed anything that could be trampled by another thread.

Comment: Is `MAXSIZE` a proper `const` variable or a pre-processor `#define` constant?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Mark Ransom already answered the question. I've updated my question, where it shows why I would like to have `MAXSIZE` as `const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can initialize a `const` variable at run-time is if it's a member of a class. Then you can use the initialization list of the constructor to set the initial value.

Comment: That would still tie the point of initialization to the point of object definition, which is the very same problem that prompted the original question.

Comment: @AndreyT, `initialize` has a strong resemblance to a constructor. This code could be trivially converted into a class.

Comment: Yes, but the problem the OP is struggling with is that he wants to set the constant's value at later time, not at the point of definition. I don't see how class can change anything in this regard.

Comment: Not totally: `int foo(int x) { static const int cx = x; return cx; }`

Comment: @TravisGockel, you should propose that as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've updated my question to insert all the code so it would make sense why do I need `MAXSIZE` to be `const`. But I guessed you already answered: **no**.

Comment: That's not the only way to do it atleast anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59851967/5676613

Comment: @Dogunboundhounds I think it has *always* been possible to initialize a `const` variable through a function, both lambda or the old-fashioned kind.  The real problem in the question is how to delay the initialization until you have the necessary run-time information available.  Maybe my phrasing could have been better.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11, u can do this

```
const extern int i; // declare in *.h file

const int i = [](){ // init
     return 10;
}();
```

Comment: Holy cow!!!! WTH. This is like black magic right here. Wtf.... This works....

Answer (score 2):

If you have to "initialize" a variable at run time, it is not a constant variable. Just make it non-constant and forget about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
const unsigned int MAXSIZE = 1000;
```

After the declaration:

```
extern const unsigned int MAXSIZE;  // THIS is a declaration
const unsigned int MAXSIZE = 1000;
```

The thing is, `const unsigned int MAXSIZE` **isn't** a declaration, but a definition and performs initialization.

Comment: Then there is no way around for that case?

Comment: @philippe after the edit, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why do you want it to be `const` if you're changing it at runtime?

Comment: I updated my question one more time, so you can see the why reason for the `MAXSIZE`

Comment: @philippe: Your update does not show why `MAXSIZE` should be a constant. Your `MAXSIZE` looks like an ordinary variable. Why would you suddenly want to make it a `const`?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can only initialize const variables when you declare them.

In your code, why not just use the argument `size`?

```
int* initialize(const unsigned int size){

   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
   // MAXSIZE = size;
   int* queue = new int[ size];
   // initialize each position to zero ( explicitly )
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        queue[i] = 0;
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
   return queue;
}
```

The whole purpose of passing a const as argument, is to ensure it won't get change inside the function.

Comment: I still think you're using const the wrong way. I mean, what's the point of setting it to const, if you're trying to change it (even once) why not define it normally, or static, and just don't change it anywhere else. I can't think of a way to change a const only once, maybe what @Mark Ransom said, but I don't know how your code is designed (oop-wise)

Comment: +1 for you! I've updated my question, so it shows more details on the design.